# Calling paintComponent() with parameters using repaint()

Tags: java, graphics, jframe

I am very new to graphics with Java, so just ask if any additional information is needed :)

I am trying to paint shapes based on where the mouse clicks on the screen. Because of this, I need to pass the x and y coordinates of where I clicked to the `paintComponent()` method so that it will know where to paint the shape.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Adding Shape");
    repaint();
}

class CanvasDrawArea extends JPanel{
    //this should run when the program first starts
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        canvas.setBackground(CANVAS_COLOR);
    }

    //here is where the question is
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g, int x, int y){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillRect(x, y, RECTANGLE_WIDTH, RECTANGLE_HEIGHT);
    }
}
```

basically I am trying to overload the paintComponent by having one that runs right when the program starts by calling the `repaint()` / `pack()` method, and one that will run when I give it the x and y coordinates. I am unsure, however, how I am supposed to go about passing the x and y parameters, as there is no way to pass them in the `repaint()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should never have the need to call `paintComponent` or `paint` directly these are called automatically by the repaint manager when required...
2. Create `java.util.List` and store the `Point` of each mouse click in it, call `repaint` from the `mouseClicked` method after you have done this.
3. In your `paintComponent(Graphics)` method, iterate over the `List` of points and paint the shape you need.

As a simple example...

[image: Dotty]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Dotty {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Dotty();
    }

    public Dotty() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new DottyPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class DottyPane extends JPanel {

        private List<Point> points;

        public DottyPane() {
            points = new ArrayList<>(25);
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    points.add(e.getPoint());
                    repaint();
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            for (Point p : points) {
                g2d.fillOval(p.x - 5, p.y - 5, 10, 10);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```